# log time after page render

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to find out the total time that page is taking to render. I have tried using `'$viewContentLoaded'` with something like this within the controller.

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', { log.timeEnd('timelogger'); });
```

But this method is called even before the angular custom directive is being executed. I am not sure

Comment: If you just want to know this for debugging reasons hit `f12` chrome, firefox and IE11 have nice developer consoles that will show you this data.

Comment: My suggestion will be to dispatch your own custom event that logs time on the link phase of the directive. Just try to figure out what gets called last.

Comment: @KyleNeedham : We would want to log the time to a database even while accessing from the mobile browser like phone. So I am not sure if we can get that using developer consoles

Answer (score 1):

A more interesting metric is probably [$digest times](https://gist.github.com/lord2800/949b87ad59344f51f391) since that's what actually causes long render pauses. However, because of the fluid nature of angular's handling of the DOM, you probably won't get useful info about render times like you want.

Comment: Thanks for those inputs. I shall try it out and see if I can log something closer atleast

Comment: I tried to use the code snippet but getting the below error.




0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property '$apply' of undefined or null reference



Below is the code 
app.config(["$provide", function ($provide) {
 $provide.decorator('$rootScope', function ($delegate) {
 var digest = $delegate.$digest;
 $delegate.$digest = function () {
 console.log('Digest on scope ' + this.$id + ' started');
 console.time(this.$id + ' - $digest');

 digest.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));

 console.timeEnd(this.$id + ' - $digest');

};

});

}]);

Comment: It looks like somewhere else in your code you're referencing $apply on an undefined object.

Comment: If I uncomment the above code, then I am not getting that error.

Comment: Unless you typo'd something, there's no reference to $apply there--only the apply method that belongs to all Function objects.

Comment: I thought so but the error is occurring within angular.js file.